# Compare two values and create combination of them in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have in Ruby

```
data = [[a, foo, 10, 1990],[b, foo2, 10, 1990],[c, foo3, 10, 1990],[d, foo4, 10, 1990], [e, foo5, 10, 1990]]
response = {{a, false},{b, false},{c, false},{e, false}}
```

Response is a result of the data and carries back with it the ID data, and a new value. What I a, trying to do is produce a new value where response is used to find all the other data in value and produce a new array such as

```
new = [[a, foo, 10, 1990, false],[b, foo2, 10, 1990, false],[c, foo3, 10, 1990, false], [e, foo5, 10, 1990, false]]
```

response will only contain elements that were in data but not all of them.

I have tried iterating over data using .each - but I cant seem to then check the response data. I do not know how.

Thanks

Comment: try to use valid ruby to describe the problem (and with real values instead of variable names).

Comment: Is it ruby? I must misunderstand something.

Comment: Try the second line of response in irb. See what you get.

Answer (score 1):

In your question (2) is not an array and (3) is not a hash, so I have to speculate what you really want.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
b = {1=>false, 2=>false}

ah = a.group_by(&:first)
b.map{|k,v| ah[k].first + [v]}
=> [[1, 2, 3, false], [2, 3, 4, false]]
```

Comment: Apologies on my unclear question, i have updated now if it helps, thanks!